# Finding Neutral element and symmetric element Of a Group

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i have $(C^{*}, .)$ and its a group.

so i have $\alpha= a+b*i$ | $\beta = c+d*i$

$\alpha+\beta = (a+c)+(b+d)*i$

$\alpha*\beta = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)*i$

how can i find the neutral and the symmetric element of this group?

Comment: You are describing the complex numbers.  You would do best to represent these as (a,b) (c,d) (a+c,b+d) etc, because otherwise we have a two different plus signs -- one for the real numbers as in a + c and one for the complex numbers as in (a,b) + (c,d).Until you show this is the same + for the real numbers, it is better to be clear.  Let's assume you have proved that C is a group under both + and *.  What do you mean by the "neutral" and "symmetric" elements?  Do you mean the identities for + and *.?

Comment: @BettyMock thanks for answer, so, this is a question from my teacher. So, i dont know how to tell this in english but, neutral elemment (a*e = a = e*a assuming * as some aperation) and symmetrical element (a*a'(inverse of a) = e = a'*a). As i said, i dont know how my teacher was assuming using this + on complex numbers. i only copy and paste what he wrote

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the "neutral" element is usually called the identity, or in this case the multiplicative identity.  In the real numbers 1 is the multiplicative identity.  It is the same in the complex numbers, but has to be expressed as a complex number -- do you know how to do that?

What he is calling the symmetric element is what we call an "inverse" or in this case "multiplicative inverse".  So given a number z = a+bi you are looking for a number w such that wz = 1 (where 1 is really the complex version in paragraph 1.

For you I think the easiest approach is to first, identify how we write "1" in the complex terminology.  Then let w = (c + di).  Multiply z * w according to the rules you laid out and set it equal to 1.  Then set the real (without i) parts equal and the imaginary parts (with i) equal.  From there it is algebra to figure out c and d in terms of a and b.

Comment: i cant remember how to do this...what i can remember is the general "shape" of a complex number -> ax+bi, correct? 1 would be 1+0i ?

Comment: Assuming 1+0i, equivalenting ac-bd = 1, ad+bc = 0, what i found was ac = 1+bd  | 
ad = bc.

is this correct?

Comment: You are right about 1 + 0i.  ac-bd = 1; ad+bc = 0 are the right equations.  Now you need to solve them to get c = (something in a and b) and d = (something in a and b).  Then you have your inverse. To get started, multiply the first equation by b and the second by a, then subtract.